# How to set bits within a bytes Object that represents hex symbols in Python

Tags: python, arrays, hex, byte, bit

I want to replace individual symbols within an object of type bytes that represents hex-symbols.

```
print(type(a)) # --> <class 'bytes'>
```

Starting with `a = b'2900BC'` I want to end up with something like `a = b'29F0BC'` by calling some function similar to

```
replace_hex_symbol(input, index, value)
```

in my case

```
replace_hex_symbol(a,2,F)
```

Meaning to set symbol number 2 in object a to the value of F (as f_hex = 1111_bin)

As far as I understand, one problem is that the object of type bytes is not mutable. Even with turning it into a bytearray I can not seem to get this done. Is there already a good way in python to achieve such manipulations or has somebody a clever trick how to replace parts within that object full of hex-symbols?

Comment: Note that this is *not* a hexadecmimal representation, but an ASCII representation.

Comment: Byte objects are indeed immutable, but you can make a *new* byte array, for example with `a[:2] + 'F' + a[3:]`.

Comment: What problems have you had turning the `bytes` value into a `bytearray()`? `bytearray(bytesvalue)` works, and the result is indexable.

Comment: Next, why use `bytes` objects here when you are manipulating *hexadecimal digits*? Why not just a list of individual characters, say, or convert that hexadecimal into integers (which then are the bytes of the value). `bytes.fromhex('2900BC')` would give you a 3-byte value.

Comment: And `bytes` are just like `str` values; both are immutable, yes, but you can still call methods on them that return a *new* object of the same type with the change applied. `bytes.replace()` works and returns a new object. `b'2900BC'.replace(b'2', b'F')` returns the expected output, `b'F900BC'`. Note that `bytes.replace()` works with `bytes` values for the value to replace and the replacement value!

Comment: @WillemVanOnserm a[:2] + 'F' + a[3:] does not work for strings can not be concatinated with bytearrays

Answer (score 1):

`bytes` objects generally have the same methods as strings; both are immutable but that doesn't stop you from creating new objects based on the old value.

For example, you can create a new `bytes` value with all `2` ASCII characters replaced with the `F` ASCII character with the [`bytes.replace()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.replace):

```
>>> b'2900BC'.replace(b'2', b'F')
b'F900BC'
```

See the [*Bytes and Bytearray Operations* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-and-bytearray-operations) of the Python standard types documentation for a list of methods that are supported. Note that the arguments to `bytes.replace()` must themselves by `bytes` values!

In terms of your `replace_hex_symbol()` function:

```
def replace_hex_symbol(a, old, new):
    # ensure that both old and new are actually bytes
    if not isinstance(old, bytes):
        old = old.encode('ascii')
    if not isinstance(new, bytes):
        new = new.encode('ascii')
    return a.replace(old, new)
```

Next, `bytearray` objects are basically a mutable subclass of `bytes`; they have the same methods, but you can also directly address indices and update those. See the [*Mutable Sequence Types* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).

Both `bytes` and `bytearray` objects are *sequences of integers in the range 0-255*, and indexing reflects this. When assigning to a single index of a `bytearray` you must use integers:

```
>>> b = bytearray(b'2900BC')
>>> b
bytearray(b'2900BC')
>>> b[0]
50
>>> b[0] = ord('F')  # ascii codepoint for F
>>> b
bytearray(b'F900BC')
```

but you could also index using slices (including in assignments), at which point you get the same sequence object again when getting, and any sequence of bytes is acceptable (including a `bytes` object or list of integers).

However, indexed access to update a `bytesarray` in place is going to be more cumbersome when you want to replace hexadecimal characters.

In fact, there is nothing about hexadecimal character sequences that states that they must be `bytes` values! You can just as well use a `str` object, or a list of individual hex digit characters if you must have a mutable type:

```
>>> '2900BC'  # string
'2900BC'
>>> list('2900BC')  # list of characters
['2', '9', '0', '0', 'B', 'C']
```

If you were instead dealing with binary data **encoded** as hexadecimal digits, then convert that encoded data to a `bytes` value with the [`bytes.fromhex()` factory method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex), and go back with [`bytes.hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex); `bytearray` objects support the same conversions.

At that point, hex digits are converted to 4 bit nibbles each, and you need an even length of hexadecimal digits:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex('2900BC')
b')\x00\xbc'
>>> list(bytes.fromhex('2900BC'))  # show individual byte integer values
[41, 0, 188]
```

and you'd have to use *bit shifting and masking* to set individual nibbles. For example, the `2` in your input hexadecimal is the most-significant nibble in the first byte, so `F` hex, or `15` decimal, would need to be shifted by 4 bits, and then combined with the lower 4 bits of that first byte:

```
>>> a = bytearray.fromhex('2900BC')  # mutable sequence of 3 bytes
>>> a[0] = (0xF << 4) | (a[0] & 0xF)  # set upper nibble, preserve lower
>>> a
bytearray(b'\xf9\x00\xbc')
>>> a.hex()
'f900bc'
```

See the [*bit manipulation* page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation) on the Python wiki. However, if you need this level of manipulation at a larger scale, consider a 3rd-party library like [`bitstring`](http://scott-griffiths.github.io/bitstring/) to make this easier for you.

Comment: It is not about replacing all occurences of 2 with f but rather setting individual hex-symbols to new values. Such as set the 4 bits behind the hex Symbol on position 2 to a certain value. In my example abouve to the value 1111 represented by the hexadecimal f

I don't see how ascii comes into play here.

Comment: @Simeon: you have an ascii string of hexadecimal bytes. `2900BC` is `50, 57, 48, 48, 66, 67` as a list of integer byte values. If you meant to have 3 values, `41, 0, 188` in decimal integers, then you need to use `bytes.fromhex()`.

Comment: @Simeon: but then you'd have to use bitmasking to set nibbles (2 nibbles of 4 bits in a byte).

Comment: I am fine with only altering nibbles

Comment: Then keep your hex strings and update individual hex digits. But then you don't need `bytes`; if you find it easier to work with a mutable type just make it a list of digits.